# Struts2 iterator increment value inside a attribute of a struts2 tag <s:form>

Tags: forms, struts2, iterator

How can I increment a form attribute like id in struts2 inside a iterator? thx
That does not work: I got a quotes error.

```
<s:iterator value="testVar" status="testStatus">
      <s:form id="<s:property value="#testStatus.count" />"> </s:form>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i solved my problem. The right behaviour is:

```
<s:iterator value="testVar" status="testStatus">
      <s:form id="%{#testStatus.count}"> </s:form>
</s:iterator>
```

hf,

Alexej

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use this easy Way to Do increment in struts2

```
<s:set var="count" value="1"/>
<s:iterator value="yourlisthere">
<div><s:property value="#count" /><s:property/></div>
<s:set var="counter" value="%{#count+1}"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<s:set var="count" value="1"/>                          
<s:iterator value="testVar" var="testStatus" status="stat">
  <s:form id="<s:property value="#count" />"> </s:form>
  <s:set var="counter" value="%{#count+1}"/>                            
</s:iterator>
```